# ¿Existe una palabra para "poner en una pecera"?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras

En español existe una palabra para poner en una jaula (enjaular), en una cárcel (encarcelar), o incluso en una cama (encamar). Y me gustaría saber si hay un equivalente para poner algo o alguien en una pecera.

Suponiendo una etimología similar (prefijo "en" para indicar dentro de o sobre + sustantivo + sufijo "ar" para indicar infinitivo de un verbo), busqué  sin éxito la palabra "*empecerar*" en el diccionario de la RAE. Tampoco tuve suerte con algunos términos parecidos como "empeserar", "empescerar" o "empiscerar".

¿Existe una palabra para "poner en una pecera"?

Comment: No creo que haya tal palabra, pero podrías construir uno (como has hecho con **empecerar*), o usando un sinónimo, **embocalar* (de [*bocal*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=bocal)) etc

Comment: No creo que funcione así la cosa. Una pecera no es como jaula, cárcel o cama....porque el pez no está "encerrado" en una pecera. Vive en el água. Y tampoco um humano se puede poner en una pecera, porque moriría....

Comment: Cualquier lógica que existe en español se puede utilisar para crear un verbo. Pero pregunto ¿La libertad de qué o de quién se estaria limitando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar "bocalizar", aunque no sería la mejor opción (y no esperes verla recogida en el DRAE).

Un [bocal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5iaFkGV%7C5idZq3k) es un tipo de recipiente de cristal, y en su tercera acepción, es un sinónimo de pecera.

> **bocal**
>
> *Del lat. tardío baucālis, y este del gr. βαύκαλις baúkalis 'especie de vaso'.*
>
> 1. m. Jarro de boca ancha y cuello corto para sacar el vino de las tinajas.
> 2. m. Recipiente usado en laboratorios, farmacias, hospitales, etc.
> 3. m. **pecera**.

Por tanto, podrías argumentar que *"bocalizar"* podría ser "poner en un bocal - pecera".

Por supuesto, dado su parecido con "[vocalizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bzSVqTr)", y en especial esa diferencia de `b` y `v` (que hará que parezca un erro ortográfico) hacen que esta no sea tu mejor opción.

Comment: cabe notar que también depende de que tipo de pecera..., el bocal es la pecera que es pequeña y redonda (como un jarrón).

Comment: enjaular o encarcerar queire decir **limitar la libertad de un animal o hombre**. No creo que bocalizar pudiera existir de la misma manera. Y encamar también implica estar "bien en su cama".

Comment: jamas he visto un pez en un bocal y pretender que goza de libertad.

Comment: @Lambie, Gracias por el comentario. Este post era más una curiosidad o divertimento para dar a conocer que una de las acepciones de _bocal_ es la de "pecera", para culturizarnos un poco (y de paso subir nuestras estadísticas de número de preguntas por respuesta, que siempre se nos olvida que las preguntas adminten múltiples respuestas y votamos la mejor...) antes que un intento de responder _realmente_ a la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, mira el comentario que pusé abajo de empecerar.

Answer (score 1):

"Empecerar" como se puede ver en este ejemplo totalmente inventado:

> —Pues enjáulalo —dijo Marta enojada.
>
> —¿Pero en qué jaula? Además, es un pez... Se va a morir —respondió Javier preocupado y confundido.
>
> —!En el acuario, idiota! —replicó Marta más frustrada que exasperada.
>
> —Pero es una pecera, no una jaula.
>
> —Entonces... ¡Entonces **empecéralo**!

Comment: ¿como llegamos a estas ediciones? , nota: No existe tal libro

Comment: entonces, ¿esto es una respuesta totalmente inventada?

Comment: Mike, deberías por favor aclarar esta respuesta. "Empecerar" podría ser la opción más obvia (y posiblemente la mejor), pero con ese "libro inventado" has causado tanta confusión que creo que la gente se abstiene de votar esa pregunta porque parece que trates de respladar ese término con un libro que reconoces haberte inventado. Creo que no necesitas poner una referencia para proponer "empecerar", solo explicarlo o razonarlo un poco.

Comment: **Update**: No entiendo los 3 _downvotes_ que tiene esta pregunta. Pese a la confusión del libro inventado, `empecerar` parece la forma más obvia de decir "poner en una pecera". No estaría de más dejar comentarios indicando claramente qué mejorar, porque en el fondo lo que estamos diciendo con esos _upvote/downvote totals_ es que esta opción no es buena o que es peor que otras, y habría que distinguir entre lo que se propone (que parece correcto) y cómo se justifica u otros problemas que tenga el post. Por favor, ayudad a mejorarlo con comentarios constructivos, no con simples votos negativos.

Comment: El verbo empecerar puede existir, el problema es que nunca existerá con el sentido que tienen enjaular y encarcerar. No existe analogia posible. Uno pone un hombre o animal en una jaula o cárcel para limitar la libertad de los mismos. Un pez no se pone en pecera para ***limitar*** su libertad: el pez vive en el água. Por eso no marcha. Solo como chiste.

Comment: interesante analogía, pero una pecera, un acuario o terrario también son una jaula pero que puede contener agua, hay animales que se pueden poner en pecera pero sin agua y siguen estando enjaulados. si no lo quisiéramos enjaular los liberariamos en su propio medio, es solo un instrumento para satisfacer nuestra necesidad de encerrar una forma de vida que nos resulta agradable y llamarle "mascota".

Comment: un animal se pone en una jaula; un hombre se pone en una jaula o en una cárcel. Las tres opciones limitan la libertad tanto del animal como del hombre y los verbos enjaular y encarcelar, también. Empecerar no limitaria el pez; el pez está libre solo dentro del água. Una pecera puede llenarse de cualquier objeto, pero su funcíón es de ser una lugar donde viven peces, en primera definición. Lo que digo se llama habla definir el trazo semántico. Si te interesa, no hay problema.

Comment: @walen lo de "confusión" viene por la causada a los usuarios, no es un eufemismo respecto a la intención del OP en esta respuesta, y es él mismo quien aclara que el libro no existe. No estoy en desacuerdo contigo, pero, como ya dicen mis comentarios, él propone una opción muy obvia que sería mejor que hubiese razonado en lugar de simular referencias. La gente es libre de votar como crea, pero mi comentario solo decía que se le explicase al usuario su error y se le diese tiempo y oportunidad para corregirlo antes o en lugar de simplemente darle -1 sin mencionar siquiera el porqué.

Comment: Como tu bien citas "vote it down. **Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong.**" que tampoco se hizo en su momento. Viendo lo que pasó a lo largo del tiempo, no creo que el OP hubiese cambiado su respuesta, y los downvotes son merecidos, pero conseguir post de calidad también implicar señalar vía comentario lo que se puede mejorar, porqué se vota negativo, etc.

Comment: Felicito a @Mike por la inventiva, que es similar a la de uno cualquiera de nuestros grandes escritores de la lengua española.